# Foreman not working with NGINX

Tags: nginx, passenger, upstart, foreman

I'm trying to use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) (version 0.31.0) to manage our application's processes but I'm not having much luck with nginx (nginx/1.0.10 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11).

Here's the relevant line from my Procfile:

```
nginx: sudo /home/ubuntu/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

When I start the app, Foreman reports that nginx is started and then immediately terminated:

```
$ foreman start
21:18:28 nginx.1   | started with pid 27347
21:18:28 nginx.1   | process terminated
21:18:28 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

However, *nginx is actually running*, even though Foreman reports otherwise.

---

Similarly, if I export to Upstart:

```
rvmsudo foreman export upstart /etc/init -a my_app -u ubuntu
```

and run `sudo start my_app`, nginx starts properly. But `sudo stop my_app` *does not stop nginx*. It continues running.

Is there a trick to getting nginx to work with Foreman?

*Note: I found [this issue with Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/94) and I'm wondering if it's related.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to run nginx in foreground mode by adding the following to your nginx.conf

```
daemon off;
```

You can specify a custom nginx.conf to nginx with the -c argument

Comment: Yep, works perfectly now. Thanks! I assume this is one of the allowable exceptions to the _"don't use `daemon off` in production"_ rule mentioned in the nginx docs for [daemon](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#daemon).

Comment: You can do `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"` instead of modifying the nginx.conf but `daemon off` is for development. Is foreman used in production?