# Setting NODE_ENV with forman causes process to terminate with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, foreman

Just altered by Procfile so that instead of having something along the lines of:

```
process: node process.js
```

I had a setup along the lines of:

```
env1: NODE_ENV=env1 node process.js
env2: NODE_ENV=env2 node process.js
```

However after doing this, running the environment with:

```
foreman start env1
```

Causes the process to just terminate:

```
11:04:37 env1.1         | started with pid 1304
11:04:38 env1.1         | process terminated
11:04:38 system         | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I found this post which may be similar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734398/foreman-not-working-with-nginx) but I cant see how to apply this to NodeJS since most people seem to have to fight to get NodeJS to run as a daemon.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Any chance you can echo the command or the std err, I am thinking that the path of node is lost as it is started?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get foreman to do that. The weird thing is everything works fine when NODE_ENV=env1 is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative route to achieve what I wanted. I passed the values in as command line arguments in forman which prevents this behaviour.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process.argv